# Open the same solution using multiple instances of Rider in macOS

Tags: rider

How do I open the same solution using 2 different instances of Rider in macOS ? I have a web application which I need to run and debug, and while it is running I need to run my API tests project within the same solution, to test api requests to the ASP.NET Core project.

Comment: You should be able to attach to two projects in the same solution

Answer (score 5):

Click on the configuration widget, edit configuration. See "allow multiple instances" checkbox next to the configuration name. But remember that you cannot occupy the same port twice. The second instance of your app should be running on another localhost.